# What currency requirements exist specifically for Commercial and ATP pilots that a Private pilot wouldn't know about?

Tags: commercial-aviation, airline-pilot, currency

Besides a different medical certificate, what other currency requirements do commercial and ATP pilots have to contend with that a private/instrument pilot would not?

Comment: §61.58   Pilot-in-command proficiency check: Operation of an aircraft that requires more than one pilot flight crewmember or is turbojet-powered.   https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=65261edeb865e8e4e6001e6495f63529&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_158

Comment: Which country or regulations are you asking about?

Comment: Why would private pilots not know about such requirements (if they're interested, of course)?  It's not like they're kept secret until you're inducted into the society :-)

Comment: @Pondlife United States primarily ... but I'd be curious if there is anything outside as well.

Answer (score 4):

**Autoland currency**

If equipped with autoland, the flight crew will have some requirement to use the system, or else autoland operation in real CAT III weather, where autoland is required, will be prohibited. For many types, this also applies to the aircraft itself.

Currency is satisfied by conducting a successful autoland in any weather, so in periods of good conditions, autolands may be practiced during normal CAT I or CAT II approaches. Crews can also do this in the simulator. All autoland use is reported to the company so they can track currency.

It varies by airline policy and aircraft type, but typical requirements may be one every 30 days, one every 90 days, or 2 or 3 landings between 6 month sim checks.

Some airlines will put a movable placard on the flight deck as a reminder to crews what the status of the aircraft is, e.g. you will see "CAT II" or "NO AUTOLAND" when the system is faulty or not current.